# SQL display parent-child relationship in one table

Tags: sql, parent-child

I have a table called `result_seq` which has 3 columns

- `STEP_ID`, `STEP_PARENT` (id of parent) and `STEP_NAME`.

I have to display both parent name and child name and the name is in the `STEP_NAME` column.  Such as:

```
STEP_ID     , STEP_PARENT , STEP_NAME; 
'{6ef83b76}', '{70207fe2}', 'Check ABC'
```

For top level `STEP_ID`, `STEP_PARENT` is null.

I'm currently using a sub-query in the select clause

```
select 
    sq.STEP_ID,
    sq.STEP_PARENT,
    sq.step_name,
    (select sq1.step_name 
    from result_seq sq1, result_seq sq2 
    where sq1.step_id=sq2.step_parent) as 'parent_name'
from result_seq sq
```

but for some reason it says syntax error.  I just wonder how other people may solve this problem

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
 SELECT 
        C.STEP_ID     as Child_ID              
        C.STEP_PARENT as Parent_ID,
        C.STEP_NAME   as Child,
        P.STEP_NAME   as Parent
 FROM result_seq P
 LEFT JOIN result_seq C
   ON P.STEP_ID = C.STEP_PARENT
```

See how is easier to read when you use better alias `C` for child and `P` for parent.

And if you want fix your current query.

```
select 
    C.STEP_ID,
    C.STEP_PARENT,
    C.step_name,
    (select P.step_name 
     from result_seq P
     where P.step_id = C.step_parent) as 'parent_name'
from result_seq C
```

But I wont recomend it because looks will have slower performace. As always the best is try both and see for your self.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the first result_sq and the second one, otherwise you'll get all the 'parent_names'. This caused the syntax error.

```
select 
    sq.STEP_ID,
    sq.STEP_PARENT,
    sq.step_name,
    (select sq2.step_name 
    from result_seq sq2 
    where sq2.step_id=sq.step_parent) as 'parent_name'
from result_seq sq
```

Or you can simply use 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'

```
select 
    sq.STEP_ID,
    sq.STEP_PARENT,
    sq.step_name,
    sq1.STEP_NAME as 'parent_name'
from result_seq sq 
left join result_seq sq1 on sq.STEP_PARENT = sq1.STEP_ID
```